# Java MySQL use BasicFileAttributes to insert imagefile last access time

Tags: java, mysql, database, file-io

```
      String sql ="insert into c_db (f_name,access_time,photo) values (?,?,?)";
      PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 

      InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fblob);

      Path path = Paths.get("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/photo/K-001.png");
      BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path,BasicFileAttributes.class,NOFOLLOW_LINKS);

      statement.setString(1,fblob.getName());     
      statement.setFileTime(2,attr.lastAccessTime());        
      statement.setBlob(3,inputStream);
```

i want to insert imagefile data(filename, accesstime) at database using Mysql.

and this is createtable

```
create table C_db(
image_id int(11) auto_increment,
f_name varchar(45) default null,
access_time datetime default null,
photo mediumblob,
primary key (image_id)
);
```

But error is

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem: The method setFileTime(int, FileTime) is undefined for the
>   type PreparedStatement at jdbcExample.main(jdbcExample.java:55)"

How to solve this problem?
Please help me

Comment: PreparedStatement interface don't have any method named `setFileTime();`

Answer (score 0):

The `set*` methods on `PreparedStatement` are not related to your field names, but rather to the type of those fields. (And if you think about it, that should make sense, because Java cannot create a new method for every single one of your fields on-the-fly.)

So, the error message clearly says that `statement` (or rather the `PreparedStatement` object in there) does not know a method `setFileTime()`. What you want to send as a second parameter is the time when the file was accessed last. Take a look at the result of `attr.lastAccessTime()`. That will be of type `FileTime`. The database does not know what this type is. You have to convert it to something the database will understand. Dates are usually handled as strings, so you could use this instead:

```
statement.setString(2, attr.lastAccessTime().toString());
```

However, this will either not work or at least not be good style. The SQL implementation knows how to deal with date values, so you could instead use `statement.setTimestamp()`, but in order to do that you will have to convert your `FileTime` object into a `Timestamp` object. That could look something like this:

```
FileTime lastAccess = attr.lastAccessTime();
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(lastAccess.toMillis());
statement.setTimestamp(2, timestamp);
```

Comment: Thank you!! But i have another error this "BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path,BasicFileAttributes.class,NOFOLLOW_LINKS);" this position error is        at sun.nio.fs.Util.followLinks(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.getFileAttributeView(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
 at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Unknown Source)                                      What is that error? ㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠ

Comment: I can't really help you debug your application step by step. You will have to learn Java properly at some point. Better start now. ;)